# python couchdbkit: how to decompress/decode binary attachment received with Database.get(... attachments = True ...)

Tags: python, binary, couchdb, attachment, compression

I'm stuck with the following problem:

From my CouchDB database I want to request a document **together with all its attachments** without making multiple calls. I'm making the following call

```
value = mydb.get(docid = key, attachments = True, latest = True)
```

This call is based on information I found under http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html and http://couchdbkit.org/docs/api/couchdbkit.client.Database-class.html#get

After the call I find under

```
value["_attachments"]["some_attachment_name"]["data"]
```

content like this:

```
woACfXEBKFUFdGh1bWJVQWh0dHA6Ly9zdGF0aWMyLmJpZ3N0b2NrcG...
```

This was supposed to be a pickled dictionary (`cpickle`, protocol = 2), but it clearly isn't, otherwise something would be readable there (and I can't unpickle it). I assume it's compressed and/or converted to base64.

I can unpickle without problems when using `fetch_attachment`, so it seems that fetch_attachment automatically decompresses/decodes while `get(...attachments = True...)` does not.

Here is my CouchDB compression configuration from default.ini:

```
file_compression = snappy
compression_level = 9
```

And here is the content of value["_attachments"]["some_attachment_name"]:

```
{
   #I use octet-stream for binary data
   "content_type" : "application/octet-stream",
   "data" : "woACfXEBKFUFdGh1bWJVQWh0dHA6Ly9zdGF0aWMy...
   "digest" : "md5-wItlEd2ZXkU3HF2TA9yiOg==",
   "revpos" : 2
}
```

So the actual question is: **How do I decompress/decode the data and what is the cleanest way to do that?**

Before someone starts asking why I use cPickle instead of directly writing the dictionary into CouchDB, let me say in advance that I have my reasons and I don't intend to go away from cPickle. I also intend to keep the compression options in my *.ini files as they are.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I almost answered my own question while asking it :D
When reading the documentation a little further I stumbled upon this:

> data (string): Base64-encoded content

So that **is** base64 code and it **is not** compressed. All I had to do was

```
import base64
...
value = mydb.get(docid = key, attachments = True, latest = True)
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(value["_attachments"]["some_attachment_name"]["data"])
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Also, when I reflect on my question, it would be kind of strange if CouchDB didn't decompress automatically compressed data before sending its response.